# Print elements of list that are repeated in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to print those elements that appear more than once in the list. can you please tell me how can I do that.. I am new to haskell.

for example if I have [1,2,3,3,2,4,5,6,5] that i want to get only [2,3,5] because these are the repeated elements in list.

Comment: this is not a write-teh-code-plz site. we expect some effort from your side. what approaches have you tried?

Comment: i tried list function combinations but its not working for me. like intersect and nub combination

Comment: i tried list function combinations but its not working for me. like intersect and nub combination. I don't need code exactly but just a right guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: First sort the list, then group equal elements and take only the ones that appear multiple times:

```
>>> :m + Data.Maybe Data.List
>>> let xs = [1..100000] ++ [8,18..100] ++ [10,132,235]
>>> let safeSnd = listToMaybe . drop 1
>>> mapMaybe safeSnd $ group $ sort xs
[8,10,18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88,98,132,235]
```

`group $ sort xs` is a list of lists where each list contains all equal elements.

`mapMaybe safe2nd` returns only those lists that have a 2nd element (= the orignal element occured more than once in the orginal list).

This is method should be faster than the one using `nub`, especially for large lists.

Answer (score 2):

[`Data.Map.Lazy` and `Data.Map.Strict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html) are host to a bunch of interesting functions for constructing maps (association maps, dictionaries, whatever you want to call them). One of them is [`fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3afromListWith)

```
fromListWith :: Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map k a
```

What you want to build is a map that tells you, for each value in your input list, how often it occurs. The values would be the keys of the map (type `k`), their counts would be the values associated with the keys (type `a`). You could use the following expression for that:

```
fromListWith (+) . map (\x -> (x, 1))
```

First, all values in the list are put into a tuple, together with a count of one. Then, `fromListWith` builds a map from the list; if a key already exists, it computes a new count using `(+)`.

Once you've done this, you're only interested in the elements that occur more than once. For this, you can use `filter (> 1)` from `Data.Map`.

Finally, you just want to know all keys that remain in the map. Use the function `keys` for this.

---

In the end, you get the following module:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

findDuplicates :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
findDuplicates
    = M.keys
    . M.filter (> 1)
    . M.fromListWith (+)
    . map (\x -> (x, 1 :: Integer))
```

It's common practice to import certain packages like `Data.Map` qualified, to avoid name conflicts between modules (e.g. `filter` from `Data.Map` and the one from `Prelude` are very different). In this situation, it's best to choose [`Data.Map.Strict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Strict.html); see the explanation at the top of [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html).

The complexity of this method should be `O(n log n)`.

I thought it could be optimized by using a boolean flag to indicate that the value is a duplicate. However, this turned out to be about 20% slower.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for the list of elements that are not unique, or in other words, the difference between the original list and the list of unique elements. In code:

```
xs \\ (nub xs)
```

If you don't want to have duplicates in the result list, you'll want to call `nub` again:

```
nub $ xs \\ (nub xs)
```

Comment: But note that nub has a time complexity of `O(n^2)`, so this might not be the most efficient method.